# Make/BASH/SH: Dead simple prefix pop and suffix swap for a string?

Tags: string, bash, makefile

Suppose I have made some non-conventional use of make.  Suppose further that I've come up with a name scheme within this usage that is elegant and useful with tools other than make, and which is *almost* fitting perfectly into the make paradigm.

I can *almost* leverage make built-ins to accomplish this task, and am looking for a bit of magic to make it 'just work' within the semantics and grammar of the system.

Right now, I have a buildable process that depends as follows:

```
# "<-" = "depends on"
foo.bar.biz.baz.new <- foo.bar.biz.baz.extension bar.biz.baz.new
bar.biz.baz.new <- bar.biz.baz.extension biz.baz.new
biz.baz.new <- biz.baz.extension baz.new
baz.new <- baz.extension

# and the following rules should suffice, where $(magic ...) is a stand-in for what I'd like to do:]
SHELL:=/usr/bin/env bash 
.SECONDEXPANSION
%.new: $$*.extension $(magic $$*)
  ...

build: foo.bar.biz.baz.new
```

What I am looking for is some magic swapper that:

```
a...b  -> ...c if ... != ""

# so, it chops off the prefix (dot-delimited), a
# and swaps the suffix only if something is present other than the suffix
```

I think this could be:

```
$(filter-out .c, $(patsubst %,%.c $(not-prefix $$*)))
```

If *not-prefix* existed, and I am wondering whether there is some built-in that more or less accomplishes this task out of the box?

Alternatively, is there some really compact bashism that can accomplish this?

For example:

```
$(shell echo "$$*" | sed -E 's/[^.]*(.*)\.[^.]*$$/\1.new/' | grep -v -E '^\.new$$')
```

Is super windy and verbose, but maybe there is some compact way to do this?

---

The most readable I've come up with so far:

```
%.new: $$*.extension $(filter-out .new, $(shell echo "$$@" | cut -d '.' -f 1 --complement))
```

**Update** Minimal verifiable example of the tree-build recursion problem:

```
%.ext:
   @touch $@

 .SECONDEXPANSION:
 %.new: $$*.ext $(filter-out new, $(shell echo "$$@" | cut -d '.' -f 1 --complement))
   @echo "@: $@"
   @echo "<: $<"
   @echo "^: $^"
   @echo $(filter-out new, $(shell echo "$@" | cut -d '.' -f 1 --complement))
```

```
$ make descendant.ancestor.new

@: descendant.ancestor.new
<: descendant.ancestor.ext
^: descendant.ancestor.ext
ancestor.new
rm descendant.ancestor.ext
```

---

Next, I add in the second "$" sign to the rule, so that it executes during the second expansion instead:

```
%.ext:
   @touch $@

 .SECONDEXPANSION:
 %.new: $$*.ext $$(filter-out new, $$(shell echo "$$@" | cut -d '.' -f 1 --complement))
   @echo "@: $@"
   @echo "<: $<"
   @echo "^: $^"
   @echo $(filter-out new, $(shell echo "$@" | cut -d '.' -f 1 --complement))
```

Which yields:

```
$ make descendant.ancestor.new
make: *** No rule to make target 'descendant.ancestor.new'.  Stop.
```

---

Ultimately, I think this should be something like:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
 %.new: $$*.ext | $$(filter-out new, $$(shell echo "$$@" | cut -d '.' -f 1 --complement))
```

But instead what I have done to make it "just work" is:

```
%.ext:
   @touch $@

 .SECONDEXPANSION:
 %.new: $$*.ext .FORCE
   @echo "@: $@"
   @echo "<: $<"
   @echo "^: $^"
   @$(eval prior=$(filter-out new, $(shell echo "$@" | cut -d '.' -f 1 --complement)))
   @$(if $(prior),$(MAKE) $(prior))
   @echo "ta-da: idempotent, depth first tree recursion @:$@"

 .FORCE:
```

Which yields a more brittle behavior than the rule line:

```
$ make -s branch.root.new
@: branch.tree.new
<: branch.tree.ext
^: branch.tree.ext .FORCE
@: tree.new
<: tree.ext
^: tree.ext .FORCE
ta-da: idempotent, depth first tree recursion @:tree.new
ta-da: idempotent, depth first tree recursion @:branch.tree.new
```

Comment: While it's in keeping with the usual level of quality/safely of shell scripts embedded in makefiles, note that `echo $@` loses a _lot_ of data. `"$@"` (when quoted) retains original data on where separators are, such that `set -- "first argument" "second argument"` knows that that `first argument` is one item and `second argument` is another; whereas `echo "$@"` just makes it `first argument second argument`.

Comment: By the way, do you have `SHELL=bash` in your makefile, or is make really using its default behavior and using `sh` instead? (If the latter, I'd suggest removing the bash references from title and tagging; as with `sh` one can't safely use facilities such as arrays).

Comment: ...all the above said, compactness is not really a quality that I often see in expert-level bash code, because part of writing expert-level code is making it unambiguously correct even in presence of data with surprising values; and given the many decades of backwards compatibility with historical bad decisions, this almost always means that code is verbose, rather than terse; being _good_ bash just means that it's fast(ish), reliable, verbose code where a reader who knows the language well can be confident at a glance that it behaves as-intended at runtime.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks -- this is great advice.  The make is using bash, but I'm not using anything like arrays in the makefile

Comment: So, I'm not anticipating answering this question since it's been decades since I wrangled makefiles professionally, so I'm not going to address the make side of it at all; but a few quick hints just looking in from a bash perspective: `${var#*.}` evaluates to everything past the first `.` in `$var` (so long a there _is_ at least one dot). And similarly, `${var%.extension}.new` trims a `.extension` from the end of `$var` and adds a `.new`. https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe is a pertinent reference, likewise [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's awesome --- thanks man, I will see how these work...

Comment: It's not a good idea to use something like `/usr/bin/env bash` as `SHELL`; make usually expects the value of `SHELL` to be a single executable name.

Comment: Your requirement description isn't completely clear.  By `...c if ... != ""` do you really mean something like `... == "" ? '': ...c` (empty string)?  Also in your examples you use the same suffix for both the RHS and LHS (`.new`)  Is it really the case that you want to support an arbitrary conversion of suffix on the right to a different suffix on the left (e.g., `biz.baz.foo` converts to `baz.bar`?

Comment: Also, what if there's no extension?  What should `foo` convert to?

Comment: @MadScientist `a...b  => ...c if ... != "" else ''` is the most compact thing I can think of; returning the null string in the case of the file with the extension only is ok.  The expectation is that `foo` with no extension should wind up being dropped.  So if I ask make to make `foo.new`, it should just make `foo.new` and not try to make `.new`; and if I ask make to make `foo` it should not try to make anything (unless `foo` is a different rule).  If I ask it to make `foo.bar.new`, it should make `bar.new` then make `foo.bar.new`, chcking timestamps of `bar.extension` and `foo.bar.extension`

Comment: You didn't answer my second question, about the suffix.  If you know that the suffix on the prerequisite is the same as the target, that's a MUCH simpler problem; basically it amounts to removing the first "prefix" and returning the empty string if there's nothing left except the suffix.  Your examples all work like this.  But your statement above uses "a", "b", and "c" which implies that the suffix on the prerequisite ("c") might be different than on the target ("b") which requires more effort.

Comment: @MadScientist Ah, then yes, the extension there is immutable -- C is always C and B is always B

Comment: @MadScientist no spaces, totally restricted to only the tree encoding, only the file name, I have total control there, and things do not get big. But, it is a buildable situation (idempotent), and third party tools are performing massive logging. So make is super quick and easy.   I have improved on the example above with the suggestions down here, but I have a feeling it is still over-complicated

Comment: No, what I mean is this: in your examples "b" == "c" == "new".  In your formula you use two different values, "b" and "c".  Is it ever the case that "b" != "c"?  Or is "b" always == "c"?  In other words, should your formula really be `a...b => ...b if ... != "" else ''`?

Comment: @MadScientist oh, yeah, sorry -- that is exactly right

Comment: @MadScientist yeah, you are right that is way easier than I was thinking.  Got in a mind-warp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK thanks for clarifying what you're looking for.  So, I don't have anything I would consider "dead simple" but you can do it wholly with GNU make using this:

```
e =
sp = $e $e
magic1 = $(if $(filter-out 1,$(words $(subst ., ,$1))),$1,)
magic = $(call magic1,$(subst $(sp),.,$(wordlist 2,1000,$(subst ., ,$1))))
```

Now wherever you want "magic" to happen, call the `magic` function:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.new: $$*.ext $$(call magic,$$@)
```

The `magic1` macro expands to its argument if its argument has >1 `.`, else expands to the empty string.  The `magic` macro strips off the first "prefix" and calls `magic1` with that value.

There may be simpler ways to do this, I didn't come up with one off the top of my head.

Also, I didn't review your edited question so I'm not sure if something you added there makes a difference here.

Comment: thanks man, I was mostly trying to avoid dropping into a subshell because my understanding is that staying in make when possible is better

Comment: It is better for two reasons: (1) performance: with few exceptions it will be faster to get make to do it rather than forking a shell (and whatever commands it invokes) to do it, and (2) portability: an in-make solution works everywhere (that has GNU make of course) while shell versions need to be written carefully and even then often don't work on Windows (for example).

Comment: I should point out the 1000 above means that it won't work if you have >1001 dots in some target :).

Comment: Nice touch on the max depth  

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that most build systems depend on stable prefixes and suffixes, with only varying stems (middle parts).

Here, you have an arbitrarily varying prefix, as well as middle part. So for instance `bar.biz.baz` is the common stem among all the names in the first dependency situation. It is arbitrary. However, each one of the names involved also has an independently arbitrary prefix, like `foo`.

To avoid fighting the tool, I would try to encode `foo` and `biz.bar.baz`, and every other such pair, together in some variables that act as the primary source of this information.

Sample Makefile. In this solution we use nothing but `call`, `firstword`, `secondword` a one-character `subst`, `foreach` and `eval`:

```
UNITS := foo@biz.bar.baz bar@biz.baz biz@baz

# $(call FIRST, foo@bar) -> foo
FIRST = $(firstword $(subst @, ,$(1)))

# $(call REST, foo@bar) -> bar
REST = $(lastword $(subst @, ,$(1)))

TARGETS := $(foreach U,$(UNITS),$(call FIRST,$(U)).$(call REST,$(U)).new)
DEPS := $(foreach U,$(UNITS),$(call FIRST,$(U)).$(call REST,$(U)).extension) \
        $(foreach U,$(UNITS),$(call REST,$(U)))

 .PHONY: all $(TARGETS) $(DEPS)

all: $(TARGETS)

define RULE
$(1).$(2).new: $(1).$(2).extension $(2)
    @echo BUILD $$@ '<-' $$^
endef

$(foreach U,$(UNITS),\
   $(eval $(call RULE,$(call FIRST,$(U)),$(call REST,$(U)))))
```

Output:

```
$ make
BUILD foo.biz.bar.baz.new <- foo.biz.bar.baz.extension biz.bar.baz
BUILD bar.biz.baz.new <- bar.biz.baz.extension biz.baz
BUILD biz.baz.new <- biz.baz.extension baz
```

Alternative, using computed variable names. Here, in addition to computed variables, which simulate data structuring, we are only using `foreach`, `call` and `eval`. No string processing at all, other than the nested variable expansion:

```
UNITS := mercury mars venus

mercury.head := foo
mercury.tail := biz.bar.baz

mars.head := bar
mars.tail = biz.baz

venus.head := biz
venus.tail := baz

TARGETS := $(foreach U,$(UNITS),$($(U).head).$($(U).tail).new)
DEPS := $(foreach U,$(UNITS),$($(U).head).$($(U).tail).extension) \
        $(foreach U,$(UNITS),$($(U).tail))

 .PHONY: all $(TARGETS) $(DEPS)

all: $(TARGETS)

define RULE
$(1).$(2).new: $(1).$(2).extension $(2)
    @echo BUILD $$@ '<-' $$^
endef

$(foreach U,$(UNITS),\
   $(eval $(call RULE,$($(U).head),$($(U).tail))))
```

Comment: I followed this advice with the @ symbol -- for whatever reason  my brain locked into a double underscore as the next step up from "." with "-" and single underscores reserved for the arbitrary components

Comment: And I'll check out the latter part over the wknd

Answer (score 0):

> What I am looking for is some magic swapper that:
>
> ```
> a...b  -> ...c if ... != ""
>
> # so, it chops off the prefix (dot-delimited), a
> # and swaps the suffix only if something is present other than the suffix
> ```

I don't completely understand the operation you want to execute, but the [GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) has, despite its name, also some practical string operations to offer:

```
include gmtt.mk
TEST := $(call glob-match,aprefix.thensomething.somemore.thenapostfix,aprefix.*.*apostfix)
$(info $(TEST))
$(if $(TEST),$(info Yes, string looks like),$(info No, string doesn't look like))
$(info aprefix..apostfix)
$(if $(TEST),$(info The variable contents of the string is "$(word 2,$(TEST))" and "$(word 4,$(TEST))"))
```

Output:

```
aprefix. thensomething . somemore.then apostfix
Yes, string looks like
aprefix..apostfix
The variable contents of the string is "thensomething" and "somemore.then"
```

PS: I want to note that the `.*` sequence in the pattern *does not* constitute the regex *[sequence of 0..n arbitrary characters]* but a *glob* pattern, where the `*` alone stands for repetition of 0..n arbitrary characters. The `.` is literal here.

**EDIT**:
Here is a solution with dynamic rules (to really generate them, replace `info` with `eval`:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

gen-rules = \
  $(if $(call glob-match,$1,*.*.new),\
      $(info $1 : $(firstword $(call glob-match,$1,*.new)).extension $(word 3,$(call glob-match,$1,*.*)))\
      $(call gen-rules,$(word 3,$(call glob-match,$1,*.*))),\
    $(info $1 : $(patsubst %.new,%.extension,$1)))


$(foreach cmdline-target,$(filter %.new,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(call gen-rules,$(cmdline-target)))
```